# Java date casting issues in date calculation method

Tags: java

I've tried to create a method in Java that will take the current date or a stored date - and get x days before or after.

```
//28 days ago
java.util.Date thresholdPast28Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -28);

//56 days ago
java.util.Date thresholdPast56Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -56);
```

the function looks like this

```
public static Date setTimeInDays(Date startingTime, Integer days){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(startingTime); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);//a day in the future or past
    return c.getTime();
}
```

I am getting errors though trying to push the today's date into this method.

```
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

-- getting today date like this

```
//today date
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); 
Date sqlTodayDate =  (Date) today.getTime();
```

Comment: Try this: `java.util.Date todayDate = today.getTime();`

Comment: Well presumably your `setTimeInDays` method is in a class that's importing `java.sql.Date` rather than `java.util.Date`. Which type do you *want* it to work with?

Comment: well - both? Its working for stored dates -- and now I am trying to get the today date and push that into the method - and that's what's causing my bug -- but then I am unsure how to convert the util.date to sql.date --

Comment: You better not use the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes at all. If you're working in Java 8, prefer the `java.time` package, and if not, either its backport or Joda-Time. In any case, check your imports, you're importing `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @procrastinator  -- "java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date"

Comment: -- @RealSkeptic - how would I convert this project to a Java 8? Also I am concerned about knocking other things out.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Try this: `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(sqlTodayDate.getTime());`

Comment: How to convert a project is too big a question to be answering here. You should work out where in your project dates are used as instances and when as local (wall) dates. But you should avoid those classes, because they are old and badly written. `Calendar.getInstance()` takes a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're trying to cast `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` in this line.

`java.sql.Date sqlTodayDate =  (java.sql.Date) today.getTime();`

You should simply use,

`java.util.Date sqlTodayDate =  today.getTime();`

So, the final working code will look like,

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date sqlTodayDate = today.getTime();

        //28 days ago
        java.util.Date thresholdPast28Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -28);

        System.out.println(thresholdPast28Date);

        //56 days ago
        java.util.Date thresholdPast56Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -56);

        System.out.println(thresholdPast56Date);
    }
}

class BasicUtils {
    public static Date setTimeInDays(Date startingTime, Integer days){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        c.setTime(startingTime); 
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);//a day in the future or past
        return c.getTime();
    }
}
```

***Note: `Calendar.getInstance()` will take some time to execute.
You can directly use `java.util.Date sqlTodayDate = new java.util.Date()`.***

If you insist on using `java.sql.Date`, the following will work for you.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date sqlTodayDate = new Date(today.getTimeInMillis());

        //28 days ago
        java.util.Date thresholdPast28Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -28);

        System.out.println(thresholdPast28Date);

        //56 days ago
        java.util.Date thresholdPast56Date  = BasicUtils.setTimeInDays(sqlTodayDate, -56);

        System.out.println(thresholdPast56Date);
    }
}

class BasicUtils {
    public static java.util.Date setTimeInDays(Date startingTime, Integer days){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        c.setTime(startingTime); 
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);//a day in the future or past
        return c.getTime();
    }
}
```